# How can I get Null when there is nothing to join with?

Tags: mysql

I am looking to set up a set of profiles for a sports team. The fields need to be dynamic so that it can be changed regularly. I don't have all the data for each player but I want to display each category on every profile, even if there is no data.

I have 3 tables that I am using for this. I have a Player table to define each player, a Profile table which will hold the categories and a ProfileData table that will link answers for each category to a player. The structure is something like this...

Player

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default       | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL          | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(45)  | NO   |     | NULL          |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------------+----------------+
```

Profile

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

ProfileData

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| category | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| player   | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| answer   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

As it stands I am using this as my query:

```
SELECT
    pc.name as category,
    pd.answer as answer
FROM
    Player p LEFT JOIN ProfileData pd
        ON p.id = pd.player
    LEFT JOIN ProfileCategory pc
        ON pd.category = pc.id
WHERE
    p.id = id
```

I have also tried this:

```
SELECT
    pc.name as category,
    pd.answer as answer
FROM
    ProfileCategory pc LEFT JOIN ProfileData pd
        ON pc.id = pd.category
    LEFT JOIN Player p 
        ON pd.player = p.id
WHERE
    p.id = id
```

What I am expecting to see is something like:

```
+----------------------+--------+
| category             | answer |
+----------------------+--------+
| Nickname             | NULL   |
| Favorite Film        | NULL   |
| Favorite Band        | NULL   |
| Look-a-Like          | NULL   |
| Alternative Sport    | NULL   |
| Sporting Hero        | NULL   |
| Favorite Club Player | NULL   |
| Favorite Drink       | NULL   |
| Previous Clubs       | NULL   |
| Age                  | NULL   |
| Height               | NULL   |
| Weight               | NULL   |
+----------------------+--------+
```

but when there is no data in the data table I get no rows back.

```
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

If there is only some data filled, I get something like this...

```
+----------+--------+
| category | answer |
+----------+--------+
| Age      | 21     |
| Height   | 5ft 9" |
| Weight   | 78kg   |
+----------+--------+
```

Comment: Problem is your `p.id` is also `NULL` in that case, therefore your `WHERE` clause removes all `NULL` rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't join to player (because you don't use any columns from player), and move the condition on player id from the where clause into the left join's condition:

```
select
    pc.name as category,
    pd.answer as answer
from ProfileCategory pc
left join ProfileData pd on pc.id = pd.category
    and pd.player = id
```

The reason your query doesn't work is because you had a condition in the where clause that could only be true for rows that joined, effectively turning the *outer* join into an *inner* join.

Conventional formatting also applied to improve readability.

Comment: Thank you! I have just tested and that is perfect. That makes a lot more sense now that you have explained it.